# Выбрать и вывести из строки слова от a до h

Tags: java, массивы, строки, циклы

Вводится одна строка целиком. Необходимо вывести те слова данной строки, которые начинаются с буквы из интервала от a до h.

Словом считается совокупность букв и символов от пробела до пробела. Слова могут быть как в верхнем, так и нижнем регистре.

Выводить слова необходимо каждый раз с новой строки.

```
Пример
Ввод: It becomes dark very fast here
Вывод: becomes
       dark
       fast
       here
```

Вроде бы я как я понял, сначала нужно перевести строку в массив строк с помощью регулярного выражения, а затем нужен цикл, в котором перебирая строки в массиве, с помощью charAt() нужно получить первую букву, которую уже проверять на верность условию и если всё ок - выводить.
Вот как раз цикл и не могу придумать...подскажите, как лучше его сделать?

```java
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = in.nextLine();
        String[] strings = s.split(" ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));
        // вероятно, здесь должен быть цикл       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(String str : strings)
    if(str.matches("^[a-h]\\w*"))
        System.out.println(str);
```

Если нужно, чтобы включались слова, оканчивающиеся на `'s` вместе с одним словом, которое идёт сразу после вышеупомянутого:

```
String s = "dark's ana here come shot";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=^| )(\\w+'s )?[a-h]\\w*(?= |$)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while(matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95406/discussion-on-answer-by----------a--h).

Answer (score 3):

Получаем из строки массив слов, и помещаем его в `TreeSet`. Применяем метод [`TreeSet.subSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#subSet(E,%20E)):

```java
String str = "It becomes dark very fast here";

TreeSet<String> set = Arrays.stream(str.split("\\s+"))
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));

// поиск слов в сете от 'a' до 'h'
System.out.println(set.subSet("a", "hz")); // [becomes, dark, fast, here]
```